# I would like to prove convergence of the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n\cdot \arctan\left(\frac{n}{1+n^2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I would like to prove the following series: 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {(-1)^n\cdot \arctan\left(\frac{n}{1+n^2}\right)} $$ 
is convergent (absolutely?) or divergent. I think $\arctan\left(\frac{n}{1+n^2}\right)$ is divergent, but I don't know how it interacts with $(-1)^n$ and how to prove it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Doesn’t your arctan piece look very much like $1/n$? Shouldn’t it have the same convergence properties as $\sum(-1)^n/n$?

Comment: As Lubin commented, there will be a problem without $(-1)^n$ but with it, it should converge.

Comment: Try the [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial series is **convergent**. To prove it, you may just use the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test):

- the function $x \mapsto \arctan \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)$ is decreasing over $[1,\infty)$, since its derivative is negative over $[1,\infty)$: $\left(\arctan \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)'= \dfrac{1-x^2}{1+3 x^2+x^4}\leq 0$,

and

- as  $x \to \infty$, you have $\arctan \left(\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\right)\sim \dfrac1x \longrightarrow 0.$

Comment: Is it possible to show it's decreasing without using derivations? Maybe $a_{n} - a_{n+1} >0$ ? And this test doesn't prove absolute convergence, no?

Comment: @Mykybo Yes, here you can also apply $\arctan a - \arctan b =\arctan \left( \frac{a-b}{1+ab}\right)$.

Comment: (+1) @Mykybo It does not converge absolutely. It is curious that this series can be evaluated exactly in terms of gamma functions.

Comment: @Startwearingpurple and how do I prove that it does not converge absolutely?

Answer (score 3):

*Leibniz's criterion* for alternating series works here: $\dfrac n{1+n^2}$ decreases to $0$, and $\arctan x$ is continuous increasing, hence $\arctan \dfrac n{1+n^2}$ decreases (to $0$).

It is *not* absolutely convergent, because 
$$\frac n{1+n^2}=\frac1n\cdot\frac1{1+\cfrac1{n^2}}=\frac1n+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)$$
Now $\arctan u=u+o(u)$, so
$$\arctan\frac n{1+n^2}=\frac1n+o\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr)\sim_\infty \frac1n,$$
which  diverges.

Comment: Shouldn't we prove that it is decreasing? If I understand it correctly, what we do is ignore $\arctan{}$ because it is a continuously increasing function, which means it behaves in a same way as if it wasn't there.
Also what criteria are you using to prove its not absolutely convergent?
Also when you got this at the end: ${\frac{1}{n}}$, by $\sim_\infty$ you mean "as series goes to infinity"?

Comment: No, I use the notion of *equivalent sequences* at infinity. This means the ratio of the sequences tends to $1$. A general result in asymptotic analysis is that two series with positive equivalent terms both converge or both diverge. Here the problem comes down to the harmonic series.

Answer (score 0):

To show that the terms are decreasing:

$\arctan\left(\frac{n}{1+n^2}\right)- \arctan\left(\frac{n+1}{1+(n+1)^2}\right)
=\arctan\left(\dfrac{\frac{n}{1+n^2}-\frac{n+1}{1+(n+1)^2}}{1+\frac{n}{1+n^2}\frac{n+1}{1+(n+1)^2}}\right)
$

and
$\dfrac{n}{1+n^2}-\dfrac{n+1}{1+(n+1)^2}
=\dfrac{n(1+(n+1)^2)-(n+1)(1+n^2)}{(1+n^2)(1+(n+1)^2)}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
n(1+(n+1)^2)-(n+1)(1+n^2)
&=n(n^2+2n+2)-(n^3+n^2+n+1)\\
&=n^3+2n^2+2n-(n^3+n^2+n+1)\\
&=n^2+n-1\\
&> 0\\
\end{array}
$